# How do I properly iterate through an array of API keys to make requests, synchronously?

Tags: javascript, arrays, web-scraping, foreach, promise

I've done a lot of work an research into this project, and am wondering what the best way to do this is. It's a script that scans for new tweets from twitter.
It may be fundamentally flawed and I wouldn't even know it.
Basically, I have multiple API keys and run requests at a staggered rate among keys.

Getting existing tweets:

```
const Twitter = require("twitter");

var i = 0;
var store = [];

var clients = [
    new Twitter({
        consumer_key: "",
        consumer_secret: "",
        access_token_key: "",
        access_token_secret: "",
    }),
    new Twitter({
        consumer_key: "",
        consumer_secret: "",
        access_token_key: "",
        access_token_secret: "",
    }),
]

const users = [
    'twitteruser1',
    'twitteruser2',
]

users.forEach(function (user) {
    clients[0].get("statuses/user_timeline", { screen_name: user, count: 1 }, (error, tweets, response) => {
        store.push(tweet.id_str)  
    })
})
```

I need help with the below (tracking multiple accounts for new tweets):

```
clients.forEach(function (client) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        setInterval(() => {
            client.get("statuses/user_timeline", { screen_name: params[???], count: 1}, (error, tweets, response) => {
                if (error) return console.log(error);
                if (!store.some(found => found == tweets[0].id_str)) {
                    store.push(tweets[0].id_str)
                    console.log('new tweet!')
                }
            })
        }, 1000)
    }, (1000 / clients.length) * (clients.indexOf(client) % clients.length))
})
```

I was working with that at first but it's not working properly as it's probably horrible written. I've tried rewriting this in many ways to make it work well and efficiently. Would map work here?

Each API key gets rate limited at 900/900 seconds, so I calculate the delays required to not get rate limited based on the number of keys I have, and run that every 1 second. E.g., 20 keys means I can have 20 requests/second, which means 50 ms staggered for 1 second.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Would clearing the interval and calling it again in the success/fail of each client get work?

Comment: Is this for a node script or front-end code?

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert with Twitter API and i'm not quite sure why you have/need multiple API keys (besides the point). I still don't quite understand what is you are trying to do.

Now, one way to make async tasks in JavaScript appear sync is to use `async/await`. If a function doesn't use promises, you can wrap it in a promise yourself (although RxJS is the new preferred way to handle async operations):

```js
const Twitter = require("twitter");

const store = [];

const users = [
  'twitteruser1',
  'twitteruser2',
];

const clients = [
  new Twitter({
    consumer_key: "",
    consumer_secret: "",
    access_token_key: "",
    access_token_secret: "",
  }),
  new Twitter({
    consumer_key: "",
    consumer_secret: "",
    access_token_key: "",
    access_token_secret: "",
  }),
];

function getTweets(client, user, api) {
  const url = api || "statuses/user_timeline";
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.get(url, { screen_name: user, count: 1}, (error, tweets, response) => {
      if (error) {
        resolve({ error, response });
      } else {
        resolve({ tweets, response });
      }
    });
  });
}

async function trackTweets() {
  for (const client of clients) {
    for (const user of users) {
      const results = await getTweets(client, user);
      if (results.error) {
        // do error handling
      } else {
        // results.tweets is defined. the listed should be sorted so no need for the .some loop call
        if (store[0] !== results.tweets[0].id_str) {
          store.unshift(results.tweets[0].id_str);
          console.log('new tweet!')
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

trackTweets();
// or at in interval/timeout/etc.
const intervalDuration = (1000 / clients.length) * (clients.indexOf(client) % clients.length);
setInterval(trackTweets, intervalDuration);
```

Now, for a situation like this, maybe it is worth looking into streaming the data rather than making continuous API calls?
Check these links, there are many efficient ways to go about this:

- https://www.google.com/search?q=twitter+api+stream+tweets&oq=twitter+api+strea&aqs=chrome.2.0j69i57j0l6.6847j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
- https://socket.io/ (they are streaming twitter right on their home page)
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io

Comment: I need to use multiple api keys due to the rate limit. With the amount of keys I have, I can submit a request very 50 ms. The streaming API is way too slow (several seconds). I need <500ms responses. I'll look into your answer!

Comment: I can continue to help; I just threw something together for demonstration purposes.